# Magento 2.3.6 - The attribute 'name' is required but missing in checkout/cart page

Tags: shopping-cart, frontend-error, error-message

I'm working on a store in Magento 2.3.6 with Porto theme, all work correctly but I have an error page when go to "show edit cart" (checkout/cart/) "The attribute 'name' is required but missing", please help me!

Test shop address is https://www.00up.app/magento2/

THANK YOU!!!!

page cart street with this error message:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.
Line: 1219

Element 'argument': Not all fields of key identity-constraint 'blockReferenceActionArgumentName' evaluate to a node.
Line: 1219

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.
Line: 1219

Element 'argument': Not all fields of key identity-constraint 'blockReferenceActionArgumentName' evaluate to a node.
Line: 1219

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem in the layout, you may not use the right code for your Magento version.

You can check again the installation guide or folder to see if you applied the correct patches.

After all, you can always ask Porto for their supports.

Comment: Hi thank you for your support, but I have tried changing theme to blank and Luma, but still have same error on cart page, everything else work without problems

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to check the layout yourself, open the layout files and find out what file causes it. Starting with catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: Please also note that original Magento doesn't have this problem, so you really should check any modifications you've made so far